# TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Tags: python, flask

I building API for ML model using flask When I enter data and then prediction, I get the following error: TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

```
    trans_date_trans_time = request.form['trans_date_trans_time']
    trans_date = pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_date_trans_time]).date
    trans_time = pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_date_trans_time]).time
    trans_date = pd.to_datetime([trans_date])
    del trans_date_trans_time

    trans_date = pd.to_datetime([trans_date])
    trans_date = trans_date.map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
    trans_time = pd.to_datetime([trans_time], format='%H:%M:%S')
    trans_time = 3600 * pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_time]).hour + 60 * pd.DatetimeIndex(
        [trans_time]).minute + pd.DatetimeIndex([trans_time])
```

this error refers to the fourth line in code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71I4J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe converting the "trans_date" to str. The "trans_date" variable is a time object of pandas.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).